# how to set one container to allow it's entire volume access to another container using docker-compose

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, celery

I have 4 services running using the docker-compose

1) `python-api`
2) `python-model`
3)`python-celery`
4)`redis-server`.

**Flow:**

1) `python-api` gets hit via postman with images and some text as parameters on port 8000.

2) `python-api` passes the image and data to `python-model` on port 8001 for some ML predictions.

3) The modified image and response data in JSON format is then passed to `python-celery` for triggering mails.

**Error:** `python-celery` is able to grab hold of images and responses that are being sent by `python-model` in step3. But it's not able to read image currently

**Error log:**

```
========================
python-celery_1      | Received task: classify_crack.tasks.queue_task_v3[d71f976f-b2e7-4b29-9147-35996668de17]
python-celery_1      | == unique_file_index
python-celery_1      | AANJkaNIJSDHURHQEYRQ(*R
python-celery_1      | /python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images/202003251237371/202003251237371_0.jpg 64
python-celery_1      | Task classify_crack.tasks.queue_task_v3[d71f976f-b2e7-4b29-9147-35996668de17] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'",)
python-celery_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
python-celery_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
python-celery_1      |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
python-celery_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
python-celery_1      |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
python-celery_1      |   File "/python-api/classify_crack/tasks.py", line 690, in queue_task_v3
python-celery_1      |     save_heat_map_v2(predictions, img_path, _dir, unique_file_index, original_image_index, i, grid_size=grid_size, metadata=metadata, StoredFileLinks=StoredFileLinks, row_stride=row_stride, col_stride=col_stride)
python-celery_1      |   File "/python-api/classify_crack/tasks.py", line 128, in save_heat_map_v2
python-celery_1      |     num_row_splits = int(np.ceil(img.shape[0]/row_stride))
python-celery_1      | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

**Line inside `python-celery` code where I'm getting an error:**

```
  img = cv2.imread(img_path)
  print(img_path)
  print(img)
  # print(img_path,grid_size)
  splits = int(np.ceil(img.shape[0]/row_stride))
```

Here, `img_path` is a valid path inside the container that is being printed. But I'm not able to read the image as `img` returns `None`. and the line `splits` giving me the above error.

**Reason why I'm getting an error:**

I'm receiving this error because it is trying to access the folder path:
`/python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images/202003251237371/202003251237371.jpg`, but `python-celery` is not able to access that folder with the name `202003251237371`.

**Proof:**

I tried using the command:

```
command: >
      sh -c "ls '/python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images' &&
```

inside the docker-compose of both `python-model` and `python-celery` services, I get the following outcome while I run all the containers again:

```
python-model_1       | 201801151543500
python-model_1       | 201801151543500.jpg
python-model_1       | IMG_20190307_184100
python-model_1       | IMG_20190307_184100.jpg
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (15)
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (15).jpg
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (16)
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (16).jpg
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (18)
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (18).jpg
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (19)
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (19).jpg
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (9)
python-model_1       | extracted_input_0_0 (9).jpg
python-model_1       | file
python-model_1       | image (2)
python-model_1       | image (2).png
python-model_1       | 202003251237371
python-model_1       | 202003251237371.jpg
python-model_1       | image_X
python-model_1       | image_X.png
python-model_1       | original
python-model_1       | original.jpg
python-model_1       | original_image_0
python-model_1       | original_image_0.jpg



python-celery_1      | 20013V_Y.JPG
python-celery_1      | extracted_input_0_0 (15).jpg
python-celery_1      | extracted_input_0_0 (16).jpg
python-celery_1      | extracted_input_0_0 (18).jpg
python-celery_1      | extracted_input_0_0 (19).jpg
python-celery_1      | extracted_input_0_0 (4).jpg
python-celery_1      | 202003251237371.jpg
```

Now clearly, `python-celery` cannot display folder  `202003251237371` with the image name `202003251237371.jpg`, which I could see in `python-model`.

How to tackle this scenario and allow `python-celery` to access such image folders?

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3"
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  app-volume: {}

services:
  python-api-celery: &python-api-celery
    build:
      context: /Users/AjayB/Desktop/python-api/
    networks:
      - app-tier
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/python-model/server/classify_crack/:rw
    environment:
      - PYTHON_API_ENV=development

    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
             python manage.py migrate"

  python-api: &python-api
    <<: *python-api-celery
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  python-celery: &python-celery
    <<: *python-api-celery
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - python-model

    command: >
      sh -c "ls '/python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images' &&
             celery -A server worker -l info"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.8-alpine
    hostname: redis
    networks:
          - app-tier
    expose:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/python-model/server/classify_crack/:rw
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: ["redis-server"]

  python-model: &python-model
    build:
      context: /Users/AjayB/Desktop/Python/python/
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      - PYTHON_API_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - app-volume
    depends_on:
      - python-api
    command: >
      sh -c "ls '/python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images' &&
             cd /python-model/server/ &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"
```

**Instance of containers:**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
7374a7b0b051        integrated_python-celery       "sh -c 'celery -A se…"   13 minutes ago      Up 5 seconds        8000/tcp                 integrated_python-celery_1
8eb9a754996a        integrated_python-model        "sh -c 'cd /python-m…"   20 minutes ago      Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:8001->8001/tcp   integrated_python-model_1
b268b7bd1ac4        integrated_python-api-celery   "sh -c 'python manag…"   20 minutes ago      Up 6 seconds        8000/tcp                 integrated_python-api-celery_1
869bb5fc21b2        integrated_python-api          "sh -c 'python manag…"   20 minutes ago      Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   integrated_python-api_1
c85a1becea34        redis:5.0.8-alpine             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   integrated_redis_1
```

Comment: This seems essentially identical to [the question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885362/cant-pass-the-intermediate-data-between-the-containers-in-docker-compose); how is it different?

Comment: @DavidMaze - yup, didn't get answers for that yet, so thought maybe I could rephrase it in a better way. Deleted my yesterday's post. Sorry for the commotion.

Comment: I don't understand how the stack trace you show is linked to a file reading error, can you clarify? Which files are involved? How is the file created in the volume by one container and supposed to be read by the other?

Comment: @PierreB. Can't we have 1 common volume that can be used by 1 container to write to it and by the other container to read from it after some time? Running the same system in local makes the celery run smoothly. Even here, in this case, ```python-model``` picks up the image from ```python-api``` and makes predictions correctly. The problem just occurs with the celery. Since it's a django app, views.py of ```python-api``` and ```python-model``` are being used to communicate. celery is inside a separate python file inside the ```python-api``` repository

Comment: Yes it is possible, but with only the stacktrace I don't understand how you are writing and reading the problematic files from each container. Showing the snippet of code supposed to write and read files may help understand your context ;)

Comment: code might be a bit difficult to share., but I'm sure of the error that container volumes are not upto the mark because 4th line of error log prints the image name, that is there, which is not being detected. Just tested the same code in local without the docker, it worked smoothly,... It'd be really helpful if you help me rectify the code for common volume container in  ```python-model``` and ```python-celery```. The code should work after that.

Comment: From the OpenCv doc: `Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but print img will give you None` - maybe your image path seems right but is wrong, can you show the output of `img_path` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenCV-Python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#using-opencv) doc: `

> Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but print img will give you None

Which seems exactly what happens here. Maybe your image path seems right but is actually wrong, possible causes:

- You are using an incorrect relative or absolute path
- Image file exists but is not valid
- Rights on folder or file `/python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images/202003251237371/202003251237371.jpg` does not allow the user running `python-celery` to read it

Your Compose volume definition looks fine otherwise.

Comment: We may verify this by checking the owner:group and mode of your file, and which user are running under each container. If you can add that to your question I'll edit accordingly

Comment: I've just edited the image path to ```img_path: /python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images/202003251237371_0.jpg```. Yet, it gave the same error. I'm using the command ```ls '/python-model/server/classify_crack/inference/images``` in both celery and model to see the count of contents.```python-celery``` not displaying folders of image names inside the  ```images``` folder. Also the number of images printed by celery are less than number of images printed by model. (for the same location at same time). Seems an access issue to me. How to tackle this? and give permissions to celery?

Comment: I also tried the command ```docker run --entrypoint ""  <image-name> whoami``` to find the user of each image. It printed ```root```. Seems like my mounting is not working properly.

Comment: The worst part is, this error exists only for few APIs, for the remaining APIs that are a subset of the APIs giving error, those are working fine.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. The image path was right and the image existed too.. Seemed like access issues. Got solved at last. Didn't do much on it. Just the stuff that I mentioned in my part of the answer., and it worked out. Full marks to you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should follow an in-depth tutorial about how to use celery with python API with Docker and Kubernetes :)

Answer (score 1):

The error got solved at last:

It worked with including following lines in python-api's `views.py`at the start:

```
    self.cur_file_dir_path = '/data/'
    self.cur_file_folder_path = '/'.join(file_path.split('/')[:-1])
    if not os.path.exists('{}/inference'.format(self.cur_file_folder_path)):
      os.makedirs('{}/inference'.format(self.cur_file_folder_path))
```

also, modified the volume name in `docker-compose`, just to avoid some confusion. Can't believe it took almost 1 week to get this solved.

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  app-volume: {}

services:
  python-api-celery: &python-api-celery
    build:
      context: /Users/AjayB/Desktop/python-api/
    networks:
      - app-tier
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/data/:rw
    environment:
      - PYTHON_API_ENV=development

    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
             python manage.py migrate"

  python-api: &python-api
    <<: *python-api-celery
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"

  python-celery: &python-celery
    <<: *python-api-celery
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: >
      sh -c "ls '/data/' &&
             celery -A server worker -l info"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.8-alpine
    hostname: redis
    networks:
          - app-tier
    expose:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/data/:rw
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: ["redis-server"]

  python-model: &python-model
    build:
      context: /Users/AjayB/Desktop/Python/python/
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    networks:
      - app-tier
    environment:
      - PYTHON_API_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/data/:rw
    depends_on:
      - python-api

    command: >
      sh -c "ls '/data/' &&
             cd /python-model/server/ &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001"
```